# Make textbox hold value on click. 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, input

I am trying to make editable text. What I have is a line of text that you click and I need an text box to appear, allowing the user to change the value of the text. With the code that I do have, when you click the text disappears. Any ideas?
html

```
       <div class="test">Click here</div>
```

jquery

```
       $(".test").click(function() {
           var inputValue = $(".test").text();  
           $(".test").html("<input value='"+inputValue+"' 
               type='text' id='box1'>");
           $("#box1").val(inputValue).select();
        });
```

Comment: You mean... the default behavior of a text box?

Comment: yes, i need it hold the value.

Comment: I don't understand.  A text box does that all on its own.  If it has a value, you click on it, nothing changes until you type.

Comment: @Brad I think he means converting a block of text into a textbox. Meaning that it should look static and then onclick the textbox shows up. Kind of like clicking "Edit" on a comment

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  @DavidNuckols, If that is what you are asking, can you edit your question so it is more clear?  The title in particular.

Comment: He just means that the textbox appears with the correct text in it, but when you click on the textbox (e.g. to edit the text), the text in it "disappears".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would be simplier if you will use existing solutions. For example: [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

But if you want (See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm8eC/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var beginEdit = function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        var input = $('<input value="' + text + '" type="text">').one('blur', endEdit);

        $(this).empty().append(input);
    };

    var endEdit = function () {
        var text = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().html(text).one('click', beginEdit);
    };

    $(".text").one('click', beginEdit);
});​
```

As a plugin for jQuery (see [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm8eC/1/)):

```
$.fn.editable = function () {
    this.each(function () {    
        var beginEdit = function () {
            var text = $(this).text();
            var input = $('<input value="' + text + '" type="text">').one('blur', endEdit);

            $(this).empty().append(input);
        };

        var endEdit = function () {
            var text = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().html(text).one('click', beginEdit);
        };

        $(this).one('click', beginEdit);        
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".text").editable();
});​
```

Comment: I'd like to limit third party pluggins.

Answer (score 0):

Take away the line `$("#box1").val(inputValue).select();`. You already set the value in the `html()` method. Also, check in the debugger that inputValue has a value.

What Graham pointed out was that when you click it turns into

```
<div class="test"><input value="Click here" type="text" id="box1"></div>
```

with a click event still on the outer div so when you click on it again it clear the text box.

Comment: Debugger has a value. It works fine, just need the value in the text input box to remain after the click in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KZWZY/) has an example. When you click a paragraph, the jQuery event handler replaces the HTML in the paragraph with a text box containing the text of the paragraph.

When you click the newly-created text box, the text in it disappears. This is because the event handler fires again when you click the text box: the HTML of the paragraph (the text box) is replaced with a text box containing the text of the paragraph. There's no text, so now you get a new empty text box.

There's a few ways you could stop this happening. When you create the text box, you could change the class of the paragraph, meaning your event handling code would no longer fire. Or, you could have another handler for the click event of the text boxes, and in here call the [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) function.

Comment: Issue is that it doesn't hold that value. I need it to hold the value on edit. Example is if you click on the text, I need it to hold the text in the box such that you can edit value eg if you need to change the value from "Bob" to "Bob Smith" you could just type in "Smith" and not the whole value.

Comment: I just tested it and came up with this too

Comment: @DavidNuckols yes I understand the issue. However the problem is not that the textbox isn't "holding the value", what's happening is that your textbox is being replaced by a new textbox, and this new textbox doesn't contain any text. I'll add another example...